# Line break \n not working in Javascript Blotter

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, blotter

I don't understand why the break \n doesn't work in the phrase "Explore \n more" of the Blotter code shown below. I would like the word "more" to go in a new line but nothing happens. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```js
const blotterElems = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-blotter]')];

blotterElems.forEach((el) => {
      const text = new Blotter.Text("EXPLORE \n MORE", {
        family: "'Butler'",
        size: 100,
        fill: "#fff",
        fontWeight: 400,
        paddingLeft: 100,
        paddingRight: 100,
      });
```

Comment: So to answer your base question, 'can Blotter render line wrapping?', the answer is no. Blotter finds dimensions for its text using virtual elements and then renders the texts in the size it believes each text to be. The author has no plans to add line wrapping support for individual text renders. [source](https://github.com/bradley/Blotter/issues/19#issuecomment-366487237)